# Does anyone here know the correct location for DeltaSPWebPartManager?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, custom-masterpage, markup, ajaxdelta

There is what turns out to be a critical component with an id of DeltaSPWebPartManager, which lives in most Master Pages. The problem is - where exactly should it go?

In the Microsoft-made master pages, seattle and Oslo, this component is in the `<body>`. But in the minimal master page created by the Design Manager, it's in the `<head>`.

If what you're putting on a page is a Nintex Form, it's a make-or-break difference: when DeltaSPWebPartManager is in the `<body>` of the underlying master page, it all works. When it's in the `<head>`, it fails rather miserably.

Why do I need to know? Because there's a definite bug in either the Nintex Form rendered or the master page. Either way, it needs to be found and fixed, and that can't be done until we can prove conclusively who owns the problem.

If you know where this component should go, please let me know.

The relevant markup looks like this:

```
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">-->
        <!--MS:<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server">-->
        <!--ME:</WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager>-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is issue / bug with master pages created by Design Manager. Default Master page put the DeltaSPWebPartManager in right location i.e in the `<body>` but the Design manager for some reason put it into "`<head>`".

to fix this issue, you have to move the DeltaSPWebPartManager into the `<Body>` tag. This is correct location for it.

Read this blog:
http://www.get-sp.com/2013/10/html-masterpages-and-updatepanels.html

Comment: Waqas, it is indeed a bug - Microsoft confirmed it to me today. Thanks very much for posting this and the link.

Comment: if this confirm, i think mark it as answer so that community get benefit from it.